# How do I extract data from an external page using json?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I'm trying to extract the text from a website (Let's just say Yahoo.com) using Ajax or jsonp. I don't really mind just as long as it works.

Here is my attempt:

```
 var serviceURL = 'http://yahoo.com'
$.getJSON(serviceURL,function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I'm new to JavaScript so I need all the help I can get.

Comment: You might want to read up on what JSONP actually is. Hint: "**JSON** + P"

Comment: You will get tons of example through just google, Check this one for example : http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_webforms_jsonp_retrieve_data.ashx